# Gemfire startup with gfsh: ClassNotFound error in gfsh start server

Tags: java, bootstrapping, gemfire

I have the following environment:OS - Windows7

**Environment variables set:**

```bash
CLASSPATH = C:\MyWorkspace\Pivotal_GemFire_800_b48398_Windows\lib\gemfire.jar;C:\MyWorkspace\Pivotal_GemFire_800_b48398_Windows\lib\antlr.jar;C:\MyWorkspace\Pivotal_GemFire_800_b48398_Windows\lib\gfsh-dependencies.jar;C:\MyWorkspace\Pivotal_GemFire_800_b48398_Windows\lib\gfSecurityImpl.jar;C:\MyWorkspace\Pivotal_GemFire_800_b48398_Windows\lib\jackson-core-2.2.0.jar;C:\MyWorkspace\Pivotal_GemFire_800_b48398_Windows\lib\commons-logging-1.1.1.jar;C:\MyWorkspace\Pivotal_GemFire_800_b48398_Windows\lib\tomcat-embed-core.jar;C:\MyWorkspace\Pivotal_GemFire_800_b48398_Windows\lib\tomcat-embed-jasper.jar;C:\MyWorkspace\Pivotal_GemFire_800_b48398_Windows\lib\tomcat-embed-logging-juli.jar;%JAVA_HOME%\lib\tools.jar;C:\MyWorkspace\Repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-gemfire\1.5.1.RELEASE\spring-data-gemfire-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar;%CLASSPATH%
GEMFIRE = C:\MyWorkspace\Pivotal_GemFire_800_b48398_Windows GF_JAVA = %JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe JAVA_HOME = C:\MyWorkspace\JDK8\jdk1.8.0_31 MAVEN_HOME = C:\MyWorkspace\Maven\apache-maven-3.3.1 PATH = %JAVA_HOME%\bin;%ERACOM_HOME%;%Cryptoki%;%WAS_HOME%\bin;%MAVEN_HOME%\bin;C:\Windows\System32;C:\Windows;C:\OtherProgramFiles\nodejs\;%GEMFIRE%\bin;
```

**My Simple Project Files:**
*cache-xml-file*:cache.xml

```xml
<cache>
    <region name="Apps">
        <region-attributes>
            <cache-listener>
                <class-name>mypackage.listener.TestListener</class-name>
            </cache-listener>
        </region-attributes>
    </region>
    <initializer>
        <class-name>org.springframework.data.gemfire.support.SpringContextBootstrappingInitializer</class-name>
        <parameter name="contextConfigLocations">
            <string>spring-application-context.xml</string>
            </parameter>
    </initializer>
</cache>
```

**mypackage.listener.TestListener**

```java
public class TestListener implements CacheListener, Declarable {
  @
  Override
  public void init(Properties arg0) {
    System.out.println("Inside TestListener.init()");
  }

  ... //Other Overridden methods . . .
}
```

**spring-application-context.xml**: contains a single bean:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:gfe="http://www.springframework.org/schema/gemfire" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/gemfire http://www.springframework.org/schema/gemfire/spring-gemfire.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">

  <bean id="myTestCacheLoader" class="mypackage.loader.MyTestCacheLoader">
  </bean>

</beans>
```

**mypackage.loader.MyTestCacheLoader:

```java
public class MyTestCacheLoader implements
CacheLoader, Declarable {

  @
  Override
  public void close() {

  }

  @
  Override
  public Object load(LoaderHelper arg0) throws CacheLoaderException {
    System.out.println("Inside MyTestCacheLoader.load()");
    return null;
  }

  @
  Override
  public void init(Properties arg0) {

  }

}
```

**Steps:**
1. Start gfsh from directory - C:\MyWorkspace\Pivotal_GemFire_800_b48398_Windows

2. start locator: start locator --name=locator1 --port=10334
3. start server:

```bash
start server --name=server1 --server-port=40411 --cache-xml-file=C:\MyWorkspace\Codebase\ContentServices\content-loaderwriter\src\test\resources\cache-loader-writer.xml --classpath=C:\MyWorkspace\Codebase\ContentServices\content-loaderwriter\target\content-loaderwriter-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

*But its throwing: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.data.gemfire.support.SpringContextBootstrappingInitializer*

I even added the gemfire jars as well as the above spring-data-gemfire jar (from my repo) in CLASSPATH variable. Still getting the exception. It seems not to resolve the maven dependencies/classpath.

4. If I try to provide multiple jars in classpath in gfsh start server command:

```bash
start server --name=server1 --server-port=40411 --cache-xml-file="C:\MyWorkspace\Codebase\ContentServices\content-loaderwriter\src\test\resources\cache-loader-writer.xml" --classpath="C:\MyWorkspace\Repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-gemfire\1.5.1.RELEASE\spring-data-gemfire-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:C:\MyWorkspace\Codebase\ContentServices\content-loaderwriter\target\content-loaderwriter-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"
```

I still get the ClassNotFoundException. Its not resolving the jars provided in the classpath.

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 1):

I think the  problem is simply that you have ':' as the separator character in your class path.  Windows wants a ';' here.  You do not need to set the CLASSPATH environment variable in this case.

However, you will most likely need other jars that spring-data-gemfire depends upon.  It looks like you are using maven so here is an easy way to get the class path for all of your project dependencies including transitive ones.

In your project directory, run "mvn -DexcludeArtifactIds=gemfire dependency:build-classpath".  This will give you all of your dependencies other than gemfire (which is provided automatically).  Add your application jar to the resulting classpath and you should have everything you need.

Also, based on what you are doing, you would probably be interested in the "--spring-xml-location" option which was added to the "gfsh start" command in 8.1.  This allows you to dispense with "cache.xml" completely and define everything in a spring context file using the "gfe" namespace provided by spring-data-gemfire.

Comment: I have tried using ';' as well as ',' - none of them are working

Comment: It may be the quotes.  They are not necessary.  Can you remove them and try again using ';' for the separator ?

Comment: Thanks for replying. I have tried removing the quotes too.. but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

@Suparno Karmakar - Not sure if you were able to resolve this issue yet, but in reviewing your CLASSPATH to the 'start server' command (i.e. the value for the --classpath option), assuming the path is correct, then one thing to keep in mind is that the --classpath option value is read into a String when passed as an argument to 'start server'.

From there, the CLASSPATH value is subsequently passed and appended to the eventual command-line String (java.exe -classpath ... JVM arg) that is used to "fork" the JVM process for the GemFire Server (using the java.lang.ProcessBuilder API).

Java is most likely treating the first forward slash () in the path information as an "escape" character", so you have to escape the escape character as in...

```
C:\\path\\to\\external\\file.jar
```

I believe backslashes in Windows will also work, therefore...

```
C:/path/to/external/file.jar
```

@Randy May is correct in stating that you can just use the 'start server' command's new '--spring-xml-location' option to indicate that you'd like to bootstrap your the GemFire Server with Spring, assuming you are using GemFire 8.1 of course.

By using this option, the appropriate Spring JARS from $GEMFIRE/lib are automatically appended to the Server's CLASSPATH on start (which otherwise are not used).

Unfortunately, there was a bug identified when using the '--spring-xml-location' option with 'start server' in that Gfsh was looking for the wrong version of the Spring JARS.  It was looking for Spring core 3.2.11.RELEASE instead of 3.2.12.RELEASE, SDC 1.9.0.RELEASE instead of 1.9.1.RELEASE and SDG 1.5.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT instead of 1.5.1.RELEASE.

Simply renaming the Spring JARs in $GEMFIRE/lib resolves this problem.

See https://svn.gemstone.com/trac/gemfire/ticket/51956, though you probably don't have access to see this bug until the release notes for GemFire 8.2 is out (~July).

Here are my bug notes...

Bug Title:

> GemFire Shell (Gfsh) throws a
>   NoClassDefFoundError/ClassNotFoundException on
>   org/springframework/data/gemfire/support/SpringContextBootstrappingInitializer
>   when launching a GemFire Server using Gfsh with the 'start server ...
>   --spring-xml-location' option in GemFire 8.1

Bug Workaround:

> When a user tries to launch a GemFire Server using Gfsh with the
>   'start server' command bootstrapped with Spring by specifying the
>   '--spring-xml-location' option, GemFire 8.1 (Gfsh) throws a
>   NoClassDefFoundError caused by a ClassNotFoundException... {{{ The
>   Cache Server process terminated unexpectedly with exit status 1.
>   Please refer to the log file in /Users/jblum/vmdev/lab/serverX for
>   full details. Exception in thread "main"
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/springframework/data/gemfire/support/SpringContextBootstrappingInitializer
>   at
>   com.gemstone.gemfire.distributed.ServerLauncher.startWithSpring(ServerLauncher.java:764)
>   at
>   com.gemstone.gemfire.distributed.ServerLauncher.start(ServerLauncher.java:696)
>   at
>   com.gemstone.gemfire.distributed.ServerLauncher.run(ServerLauncher.java:626)
>   at
>   com.gemstone.gemfire.distributed.ServerLauncher.main(ServerLauncher.java:200)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.springframework.data.gemfire.support.SpringContextBootstrappingInitializer
>   at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366) at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355) at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354) at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425) at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308) at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358) ... 4 more }}}
>   GemFire is incorrectly specifying the Spring LIBS as version
>   3.2.11.RELEASE when GemFire in fact shipped with Spring 3.2.12.RELEASE JAR files. In addition, the Spring Data Commons JAR file is
>   incorrectly identified as spring-data-commons-1.9.0.RELEASE.jar,
>   however, GemFire 8.1 shipped with
>   spring-data-commons-1.9.1.RELEASE.jar. Note that GemFire/Gfsh in 8.1
>   is correctly specifying the Spring Data GemFire JAR file with
>   spring-data-gemfire-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar See Bugnote workaround to
>   resolve this issue.

Bug Workaround:

> There are 2 ways to resolve this issue: 1. First, and the tried and
>   tested procedure is to... 1.1 Download and copy the Spring
>   3.2.11.RELEASE JAR files into the $GEMFIRE/lib directory. For every Spring 3.2.12.RELEASE JAR file in $GEMFIRE/lib, copy the corresponding
>   3.2.11.RELEASE JAR into $GEMFIRE/lib. 1.2 Next, download and copy the spring-data-commons-1.9.0.RELEASE.jar file into $GEMFIRE/lib. 1.3
>   Finally, perform the following... $ cp
>   $GEMFIRE/lib/spring-data-gemfire-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar
>   $GEMFIRE/lib/spring-data-gemfire-1.5.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar --- NOTE:
>   Unfortunately the bug is that Gfsh is looking for the wrong version of
>   these particular Spring JAR files. --- 2. The other option, is to
>   manually specify the Spring JARS and versions yourself using the
>   '--classpath' option to the 'start server' command. Note, in GemFire
>   8.1, the '--classpath' option has been changed to a "prepend" option, and therefore, effectively overrides any GemFire lib dependency in the
>   $GEMFIRE/lib directory. Caution, however care should be taken when
>   overriding any of the GemFire lib dependencies. NOTE, this "prepend"
>   behavior does not apply to the 'gemfire.jar' file itself for security
>   reasons.

Hope this helps!  Post back if you still have problems.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Please replace the separator ":" to "\;"
You need to add the escape character before the windows separator. Otherwise, gfsh will treat the ";" as the ending of one command.